# Game Background - Proper Resolution for a PNG file?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making an adventure game with a non-scrolling background in SpriteKit for iOS / Swift. The background won't change, but the things that spawn on it will.

On some tutorials online, specifically following this one, https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/14/overview,  the author used a 1024 x 768 background for @1x, and then 2048 x 1536 for @2x. The author didn't have a @3x.

I read that to get @2x just multiply 2 for 2x, but now that I have to support @3x, you would multiply the original by 3?

So that means

```
@1x = 1024 x 768
@2x = 2048 x 1536
@3x = 3072 x 2304
```

Does that seem correct? The @3x seems awfully high. Is this just how I will do it with all my asset? i.e. if the character on the 1024 x 768 @1x background is 200x200px, then I would make him 400x400 on the 2048x1536 background, and 600x600 on the 3072x2304 background?

Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind: currently, only the 7+ and 6s+ use @3x resolution images. iPads only use @2x. So no (current) iOS device uses `3072 x 2304`

Comment: Do you think it's smart to use @3x and those sizes? I'm sure it would add a lot more size to my game.

Comment: I suggest taking a read through this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW1 ... also looks like a good blog posting here: http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/ios-design-guidelines

Comment: Not really...  What is the largest iPhone screen size?  What is the largest iPad screen size?  No iPhone or iPad device is capable of displaying 3,072 px x 2,304 px.

Comment: @el-tomato If my background at 3x exceeds what Apple even shows, then I assume it scales it down. So honestly I could probably just re-use the 2x background for the 3x.  Now for the player, would you still say that I should use him at 600x600 since that dimension *is* supported? i.e. 1x was 200x200 2x was 400x400 and 3x was 600x600 but on the 2x background now. Thoughts?

Comment: Why would you even use an image of 3072 x 2304 as a scene background when you already know no device is capable of displaying that many pixels?  And why would you even want to use three different sizes when you know one size can serve all devices?  I would read one or more books, as I have already done, if I were you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are keeping the same proportion each time.

`3072/600 = 5.12 = 1024/200`

`2304/600 = 3.84 = 768/200`

Comment: Yes, use the same resolution you have if you are planning to use @3x

Comment: According to the guy above, and on the apple guidelines, the highest resolution even supported right now is 2732 x 2048. Does that mean if i used 3x of higher resolution, it wouldn't matter as it would scale down to 2732 x 2048 anyway? Do you think I should still go higher for future proofing?

Comment: I'm going to be honest, I've never developed in swift. However, I would design your code to be dynamic as possible to accept a variety of resolutions. Future proofing is never a bad thing, and you can always downscale